# Why htaccess rules in subfolder stops parent htaccess rules from working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following directory structure

```
.htaccess
subfolder
  .htaccess
  file.php
```

/.htaccess contains rules to force ssl on the whole site. /subfolder/.htaccess contains rules to allow accessing php files without their extension. Both rules work, unless used together. If I access http://example.com/subfolder/file, it'll correctly load file.php but it will not redirect to https. What do I need to change in my .htaccess files to make both rules work together?

This is unexpected behavior to me because if I understand correctly, the htaccess in a subfolder runs before the htaccess in the parent folder. But if I paste the force-ssl rules at the end of subfolder/.htaccess then it works as expected. What is causing this behavior difference?

/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302]
```

/subfolder/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA]
```